# iphone distribution identity missing from code signing

Tags: iphone, code-signing, identity

iphone distribution identity is missing from code signing but in iOS dev center under the provisioning profile have both certificate.

Now to make iPhone distribution identity appear in code signing.

Thanks for help.

Comment: refer the apple Answer : its working for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/35401483/4524276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto your target settings, code sign section, then select distribution profile.
[image]

Comment: But i don't see distribution profile in code sign section to select

Comment: @user1452248, then goto xcode organizer and confirm your provisioning profile is valid and status in green color. If it is not valid then you need to install certificate(.p12) in keychain access.

Comment: Yeah that is what exactly i did. I think distribution profile is missing from code sign because it is not matching with the bundle identifier of the app. my identifier i think is  com.something.abc but my profile maybe created for com.something.xyz. because later on i changed my project name. So how i can fix this issue

Comment: now bundle identifier in app and provisioning profile is same or different? If not same then no way..u need to create new provisioning profile, If same and still getting problem then download your distribution certificate and provisioning profile again and install. This sure solve your problem..