# ERROR ITMS-90034: Missing or invalid signature

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

*Every time trying to submit but some result. Like this*

**ERROR ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle '****.******.****' at bundle path 'Payload/APP_NAME.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate."**

Everything looks fine, we click submit, it goes to validate, and starts to upload to the app store. Then at the very last second ,the error pops up no matter what we've done to try to fix it.

Tried following steps to.

1) Tried to make just new app and upload ( With this excluded depending from any framework or source and any settings) - some result

2) Tried to remove account from Xcode->Preferences->Account (Remove account) and then add again.

3) Tried revoke certificate make again and then refresh provisioning profile

4) Tried to make app zip and upload from Application Loader

5) Tried to make IPA

6) Make change in Keychain Access for related Certification Authority certificate from "Always Trust" to "Use the system default".

7) remove all certificates and provisioning profiles and add again.

The build is valid

[image]

Some Error for every time, when trying to upload for submission.

Error from Application loader.

[image]

Error from Organizer.

[image]

Has anyone been able to work through this or a similar issue, and can you help?

Comment: what certificate do you actually use? :) you can check it in the log of the build

Comment: It is correct, when I trying compile with Ad Hoc it working

Comment: "Ad Hoc" means when you sign with an "Ad Hoc" provisioning profile it works and you can deploy to the related AdHoc iOS devices (without using XCode + cable) but failed to submit with another provisioning profile for AppStore?

Comment: Any Solution? I am still facing this issue?

Comment: Any Solution? I am still facing this issue?

Answer (score 22):

I have just got the same issue. I have restarted `XCode` and it works like a charm!

I have not changed anything and it was working an hour ago; therefore, I did not spent any time on `keychain`. I have simply restarted `XCode` and it has worked.

If the problem still persists, then I recommend you to Go to Keychain Access, delete all the expired certificates, and add the corresponding valid certificate.

Comment: Restarting Xcode worked for me as well. 
My situation was that I had to update provisions before uploading to AppStore, and it seemed like Xcode recognized them when archiving the build, but the error persisted. So I restarted Xcode, re-archived the same build and uploaded to AppStore one more time without changing anything else. It worked.

Comment: Restarting XCode also worked for me. I feel like IT department made a remote OS upgrade yesterday which might have caused the issue.

Comment: Yes, just do restart XCode. It has helped, just checked. As always... (

Answer (score 20):

you can try... Make change in Keychain Access for related Certification Authority certificate from "Always Trust" to "Use the system default".

This do the trick for me!
[image]

Comment: Very strange. Try to remove all certificates from terminal "~ / Library / MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles"

Comment: I'm very sorry I have no other ideas. You can try from another Mac ... :)

Comment: Great. if you think that my help was useful I would love a small vote. Thank you.

Comment: You can hit this error if you have Always Trust on your iPhone Distribution certificate as well.  In short, watch out for the little blue plus on any cert in your login keychain.

Answer (score 7):

I have resolved this many times:

1. check AppleWWDRCA certificate if expired or not.
2. check fields for always trust by double click the distribution certificate in keychain.
3. I was using another distribution certificate from same name with another expiry date.
4. update/delete previous distribution installed certificate

Answer (score 7):

I got the same issue today. My app was sent successfully, but after 10 mins I got an email. with this Error ITMS-90034. As result, I started to check If my profiles are expired and etc. Everything was fine. So maybe after few hours I just sent a new archive, and it was successfully uploaded. I guess it was related to the apple side.

Comment: the same happened to me at the exact same time

Comment: @kubilay solved. check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66658640/7541231

Comment: @ivan8m8 Actually, I submitted again and it worked -but thanks.

Comment: Worked just resubmitting again after 10 minutes for me

Answer (score 4):

It works for me in few days ago. But, Today 2016/2/22, I use the same step to do all of setting not change after one day work still can't upload to App store. I don't know whats going on. Does anyone has solved this problem.

Finally, I find a good solution to solve this issues first download and install the new [WWDR intermediate certificate](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer) (by double-clicking on the file). deleting the expired certificate from keychain . Then all of problem is solved. Here for reference [Xcode 7 error: “Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for …”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35401483/1192293)

Answer (score 2):

I have two certificates with same bundle identifier. One was revoked and one was valid. 
I deleted the revoked one and it worked for me.
Reason of Error: Compiler could not figure the correct certificate (unknown).

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be raised because of distribution certificate with private key not present in the keychain or revoked from apple developer account.

We can fix this issue by two ways :

1. Create distribution certificate on apple developer account. download it and add it in keychain. Make sure this certificate is added in login section with private key.
2. If distribution certificate is already created on any other machine that time you can take distribution certificate with private key by selecting distribution certificate and private key, export both items to specific destination path. After take that certificate and add it in keychain.

Happy Coding ...

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was the **Signing Certificate** at the *MyProject -> Signing & Capabilities -> Release* page differed from the **common** name of the Distribution certificate at the *Organizer* page.

The common name could be found in *Keychain Access* by a right click at a certificate name and then *get info*.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Keychain Access, delete all the expired certificates, and add the corresponding valid ones.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same issue, i was selecting Automatically Signing on xCode and manually distribution certificate at uploading time. 
then i tried manually certificate on both places.(Xcode and TF.) Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to generate a provision profile again, from the apple developer page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the same profile in Signing and Capabilities either the one you're in `Product -> Archive`.
Checking that worked for me! I use manual signing and didn't realize I had different profiles.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133781?answerId=423098022#423098022

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to revoke all certificates you have duplicated in developer.apple.com account under certificates, I kept my `distribution` certificate.

Make sure to revoke all **other** `distribution` or `development` certificates associated to your name.

Go to Xcode and submit it again, with letting Xcode automatically sign it.