# Errors submitting app to App Store from Xcode and Application Loader

Tags: ios, app-store, ios-provisioning, submission

While submitting I get errors:

1. If I send via xCode I receive `"This action could not be completed -22421"`
2. If I send via Application Loader I get `"ERROR ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle '  ' at bundle path 'Payload/.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate"` and this `"The resulting API analysis file is too large. We were unable to validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an informational message."`

Before submitting I did remove all previous certificates, keys and provisioning profiles and create new distribution certificate and provisioning profile.

Comment: Can you explain your steps for creating the build that you are submitting through the Application Loader?

Comment: SOLVED!!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for/35401483#35401483

Comment: FYI, I added the answer to ensure others can find the solution quickly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR ITMS-90034: Missing or invalid signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775122/error-itms-90034-missing-or-invalid-signature)

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by having the old, expired WWDRCA (World Wide Developer Relations Certificate Authority) intermediate certificate still on your system.

First, download the [WWDRCA cert](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer).  Open it to add it to your keychain.

Next, in the Keychain Access application, select the System keychain. Make sure to select “Show Expired Certificates” in the View menu and then delete the expired version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority Intermediate certificate (expired on February 14, 2016).

Your certificates should now appear as valid in Keychain Access and be available to Xcode for submissions to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create ipa with Production certificate and Distribution Provisioning Profile.

Then,you can upload that ipa with application loader and issue will be resolved.