# Error: ITMS-90034: Missing or invalid signature is not signed using an Apple submission certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I use `Ionic` when I upload the app it doesn't give me problems but then apple sends me an email with this text.

[image]

Look for a solution and do what it says in this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33775343/2400373

But it does not work. What can be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40981438/2400373

Then, I update the version in my code:

[image: code]

After `Product -> Archive` The Result of upload is OK for Apple

Regards.