# How to solve Cordova IOS upload issue ERROR ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Hello I keep getting this error,

```
App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature" ##### is not signed using an Apple submission certificate
```

when trying to upload my .ipa bundle to the Apple store using Xcode 11.31.

I have tried so many recommendations that I have seen online.

e.g

1. delete and recreate all certificates and profiles.
2. change build settings to legacy
3. assign trust to my certificates

Nothing seems to get this working.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR ITMS-90034: Missing or invalid signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775122/error-itms-90034-missing-or-invalid-signature)

Comment: Have you tried using automatic signing in Xcode?