# Xcode 7 can't upload new version

Tags: xcode, swift

I would like to submit a new version to the App Store from Xcode.
But if I would like to upload it, I get this message.

[image]

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apples WWDR intermediate certificate certificate has expired. You have to renew it!

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35401483/4906484