# Affect an app awaiting release? -- Xcode 7 error: “Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for …”

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing, testflight

There was recently a question about a signing identity error that was answered here:

[Xcode 7 error: "Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for)

I fixed the error on my machine so I can upload more versions of my app to the App Store. No problems there.

The question now becomes: will this certificate issue affect an app that's already in the App Store?

I have an app that has been approved that will be released in about a month. Will users who download the app in a month have any problems because of an expired certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: how did you fix the issue?

Comment: To fix the certificate issue, I just followed the instructions given in the checked answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. NO, this certificate issue **won't affect** an app that's already in the App Store.
2. Users who already download the app **won't get any problem**. The apps will be available for user to download and use without any issue as long as you pay the yearly subscription fee.
   Only if your account deactivated , it will remove the apps from appstore.

Comment: Thanks for the info!