# Xcode fails generating matching signing assets

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I have some applications on Appstore which uses an iOS Distribution certificate.
recently I got this error:
[image]

But I don't have any other Macs using this certificate.

- How could I see the list of Macs on which this certificate is installed
- What should I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the same error I was getting, then its apple fault.

Please see here :
[Xcode 7 error: "Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for)