# Code signing issue Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

*I created this thread because I want to show my screenshots and the other posts didn't solve my issue.*

Good morning,

I'm trying to implement a notification feature in my first iOS app and I'm having a lot of problems regarding the "code signing" options in the Xcode. I have followed the tutorial from Batch.com (the service I'm using to deploy notifications) but it's not working. I assume that it's something that I'm not doing right, so I'm going to post some screenshots because I don't know how many times I tried to make it correct.

Everything seems to be fine (no error or warning in Xcode) but when I "Archive" my App in order to upload it to my itunes connect, it displays the following error:

**"Missing iOS Distribution signing identity..."**

Much appreciated if someone can show me some tutorial, guide or a reply because I don't know what else to try.

**Push Notifications**

[image: Push Notifications]

**Provisioning profile (Distribution)**

[image: Provisioning profile (Distribution)]

**Provisioning profile (Development)**

[image: Provisioning profile (Development)]

**Certificates** The 2nd and the 3rd are created with the following process: App ID > (App name) > Enable notifications > Create certificate

[image: Certificates]

**Code signing from Xcode 7.2**

[image: Code signing]

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

That's my **Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority** screenshot:

[image: Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7 error: "Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for)

Comment: I have tried following that solution and that's why I created the topic with my own screenshots, because it didn't solve my problem. Thanks @MuhammadAdnan, I tried to choose "Production" and it didn't work, I receive the same message.

Comment: please confirm that your Apple world wide certificate is not expired in keychain settings. Apple world wide Certificate got expired on Feb 14 2016. That is to be deleted from keychain and reinstalled .

Comment: Done @MuhammadAdnan, my certificate is fine, isn't it?

Comment: yes certificates are fine.Recreate Distribution provisional profile and create archive again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Code Signing identity Select Distribution Certificates of Provisioning Profile and Developer Certificate.

If you don't have those certificate you must create them, then download and double click to install it.**
@Jordi Visit following link, that explains right from scratch to develop First Push notification App.

[Ray Wenderlich Push notification tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: Thanks @Avinash, I will try again with this tutorial because my notifications are fine (when I send a test from Batch.com to my device. The problem is when I have to upload it to my Itunes connect account.

Comment: Go to your Apple Developer account. Check have you created Distribution provisioning profile for your app with app id?

Comment: Hi @Avinash, do you mean the second screenshot I take from my "member center"? That's the Distribution provisioning profile I created and I chose my App ID. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes it is. Download it, double click to install it then choose Distribution in Project Target Code signing identity at all places. then build project again and try to upload.