# Missing IOS distribution signing identity for

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

I'm trying to Validate my app on xcode and I'm having this error pop up when I try to do so. I've read that I should delete and re-add my login certificates in keychain access as well as the system ones. But this doesn't seem to do anything in my case.

The error I get on the certificate is as follow: 
"This certificate has an invalid issuer"

I would like to point out that when I click the drop down on the certificate it says a IOS developer but its kind is a private key.

does anyone have a similar problem?

Many thanks

[image]

I just wanted to add this image to give people a better understanding of my keychain access.. All the ones that aren't highlighted are giving me the above mentioned error.

**** Update ****

[image]

Comment: Certificate which is shown as selected in given image is not Developer/Ad Hoc/Distribution certificate for app signing. Its signing certificate, you need to use first certificate "iPhone Developer: Max Lynn" to sign your application and build. Make sure you have created your provisional profile using the same certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm not sure I understand, how can I make sure that I'm using "iPhone Developer: Max Lynn"?

Comment: To check current certificate in use Go to Project Navigator->Target->Build Settings->Under Code Signing->Under Code signing identity. Select appropriate certificate which fits your provisional profile & bundle identifier using dropdown.

Comment: Read in detail about it in Apple document section [Maintaining Your Signing Identities and Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

Comment: Please See This Link :-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for

Comment: Dipen, I can't see an option for project navigator. I've updated the question with another screenshot hoping this can help for a solution