# Xcode - Failed to locate or generate matching singing assets: Permissions failure

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I'm trying to export a iOS app ipa file using Xcode, but  I get the error:

[image]

The ipa is for Enterprise deployment. It 's a new error for me.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: plz check your distribution certificates in your key chain

Comment: Yes, actually in my key chain certificates are marked as "not valid emissor"

Comment: create new certificate for distribution on devloper account .

Comment: I solve it thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for

Answer (score 4):

1) Check that you have the correct Team selected under the General tab

2) Check that your bundle ID is correct under the General tab and that it matches an AppId that you must have already configured in member center. MUST MATCH EXACTLY, case sensitive

3) Check that you have the distribution cert in your LOGIN keychain and that it can be expanded to show a PRIVATE KEY

4) Check your code signing settings under Build Settings say DEVELOPER for both (including release)

5) Check that you have created and downloaded a provisioning profile for the correct App ID from the member center and that you have installed it into Xcode. This can also be accomplished via Xcode preferences

Comment: #5 worked for me. `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Download all profiles`