# Missing ios distribution signing identity xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

This is the problem I have, I can't validate my archive from Xcode even though I have all my certificates. I've tried some of the solutions that I've found in stack overflow but non of them worked, I've already changed the AppleWWDRCA.cer, here are some screenshots of my certificates and Xcode. hope you can help me.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) You are not creating `Provisioning Profiles` for your certificates.
2) Add screen from the `Build Settings` -> `Code Signing` section

Comment: What version of Xcode is this? Did you try _everything_ in all the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for ?

Comment: @matt thank you, I had to delete the old certificate from sisters in keychain, didn't see it before.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Downloading the distribution certificates.
2. Opening them in Finder.
3. Double clicking them to integrate in your Keychain.

Answer (score 0):

This were the steps I followed to make it work.

1) Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

2) Double-click to install to Keychain.

3) Then in Keychain, Select View -> "Show Expired Certificates" in Keychain app.

4) It will list all the expired certifcates.

5) Delete "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority certificates" from "login" tab.

6) And also delete it from "System" tab.